Recuperación de contraseña con envío de token por correo no funciona
Estoy desarrollando una plataforma en la que hay 3 tipos de usuarios. Los usuarios se registran cosa que funciona correctamente, y deberían de poder recuperar contraseña.
Cuando el usuario pincha en recuperar contraseña, se abre la página para que ingrese el email y pinchar en recuperar contraseña. Lo que debería de hacer la aplicación es enviar un email con un token y en la página en la que escribe la nueva clave también pone el token enviado por correo electrónico.
El problema es que no está enviando el email con el token. Espero que podáis ayudarme. Os dejo aquí la tabla y los archivos recupera_pass.php, que es el archivo que envía el email y recuperar_clave.php que donde el usuario debería de poner la nueva clave. Tengo la librería PHPMailer en la raíz del proyecto
esta es la tabla usuario:
Estructura de tabla para la tabla usuarios
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `id_supervisor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_grupo_usuario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` enum('A','B','C','D') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

este es el archivo recupera_pass.php
       // Incluir archivos de PHPMailer
       require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
       require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
       require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
       
       // Iniciar la sesión
       session_start();
       
       // Verificar si el usuario ya está autenticado, redirigirlo al dashboard si es así
       if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true) {
           header('Location: dashboard.php');
           exit;
       }
       
       // Incluir el archivo de conexión a la base de datos
       include('includes/db.php');
       
       // Inicializar variables para almacenar mensajes de error y éxito
       $errors = array();
       $success = '';
       
       // Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario de recuperación de contraseña
       if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
           // Recuperar y validar el correo electrónico ingresado
           $email = trim($_POST['email']);
       
           // Verificar si el correo electrónico existe en la base de datos
           $query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?";
           $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
           mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
       
           if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
               // El correo electrónico existe, generar un token y enviar un correo electrónico con un enlace de restablecimiento
               // Generar un token único
               $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
                       
               // Calcular la hora de expiración del token (por ejemplo, 1 hora después de ahora)
               $token_expires = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour'));
                       
               // Actualizar la tabla de usuarios con el token y la hora de expiración
               $update_query = "UPDATE usuarios SET reset_token = ?, reset_token_expires = ? WHERE email = ?";
               $update_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $update_query);
               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_stmt, "sss", $token, $token_expires, $email);
               mysqli_stmt_execute($update_stmt);
       
               // Obtener el nombre del usuario
               $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
               $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
               $nombre = $row['nombre'];
       
               // Enviar correo electrónico con el enlace de restablecimiento
               try {
                   // Crear una nueva instancia de PHPMailer
                   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
               
                   // Configurar el servidor de correo
                   $mail->isSMTP();
                   $mail->Host = 'mail.we4you.viessmannes.es';
                   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                   $mail->Username = 'info@we4you.viessmannes.es';
                   $mail->Password = 'contraseña';
                   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
                   $mail->Port = 465; // Puerto SMTP
       
                   // Configurar el correo electrónico
                   $mail->setFrom('info@we4you.viessmannes.es', 'Plataforma xxxxxxx');
                   $mail->addAddress($email);
                   $mail->Subject = 'Restablecer Contraseña';
                   $mail->isHTML(true);
                   $mail->Body = 'Hola ' . $nombre . ', por favor haz clic en el siguiente enlace para restablecer tu contraseña: <a href="https://we4you.viessmannes.es/reset.php?token=' . $token . '">Restablecer contraseña</a>';
       
                   // Enviar el correo electrónico
                   $mail->send();
       
                   // Mostrar mensaje de éxito
                   $success = "Se ha enviado un correo electrónico con instrucciones para restablecer tu contraseña.";
               } catch (Exception $e) {
                   // Mostrar mensaje de error si falla el envío del correo electrónico
                   $errors[] = "Error al enviar el correo electrónico: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
               }
           } else {
               // Mostrar mensaje de error si el correo electrónico no está registrado
               $errors[] = "No se encontró ningún usuario con el correo electrónico proporcionado.";
           }
       
           mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
       }
       ?>
       
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="es">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <title>Recuperar Contraseña</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       </head>
       <body>
           <div class="container mt-5">
               <div class="row justify-content-center">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="card">
                           <div class="card-header">
                               Recuperar Contraseña
                           </div>
                           <div class="card-body">
                               <?php if (!empty($errors)) : ?>
                                   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                       <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
                                           <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
                                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                                   </div>
                               <?php endif; ?>
                               <?php if (!empty($success)) : ?>
                                   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                       <?php echo $success; ?>
                                   </div>
                               <?php else : ?>
                                   <form action="recuperar_clave.php" method="post">
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                           <label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label>
                                           <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                                       </div>
                                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Recuperar Contraseña</button>
                                       <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-danger">Volver</a>
                                   </form>
                               <?php endif; ?>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </body>
       </html>

Y este es el archivo recuperar_clave.php donde el usuario pondría el token recibido y la nueva clave.
    <?php
    session_start();
    
    include('includes/db.php');
    
    $errors = array();
    $success = '';
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $token = trim($_POST['token']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
        // Verificar si el token y la contraseña no están vacíos
        if (empty($token) || empty($password)) {
            $errors[] = "El token y la contraseña son obligatorios.";
        } else {
            // Verificar si el token es válido
            $query = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE reset_token = ? AND reset_token_expires > NOW()";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $token);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                // El token es válido, actualizar la contraseña del usuario
                $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $update_query = "UPDATE usuarios SET password = ?, reset_token = NULL, reset_token_expires = NULL WHERE reset_token = ?";
                $update_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $update_query);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_stmt, "ss", $hashed_password, $token);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($update_stmt);
    
                $success = "¡Contraseña restablecida con éxito!";
            } else {
                // El token no es válido
                $errors[] = "El token de restablecimiento de contraseña no es válido o ha caducado.";
            }
    
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Restablecer Contraseña</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Restablecer Contraseña
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <?php if (!empty($errors)) : ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
                                        <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (!empty($success)) : ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    <?php echo $success; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <form action="recuperar_clave.php" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="token">Token de Restablecimiento:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="reset_token" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Nueva Contraseña:</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Restablecer Contraseña</button>
                                </form>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

El email con el token no se envía y por lo tanto el usuario no puede ponerlo con la nueva clave. Me podéis ayudar?

Salta algún error?

@Yussef, No, ningún error, no envía el correo y no puedo comprobar si al poner el token está correcto todo

Te recomiendo crear un script PHP simple, que solo envíe un correo (sin involucrar bases de datos, ni validaciones ni nada) y desde ahí tratar de solucionar el problema

Tienes un error en $mail->Password = 'contraseña; Como ya te dijeron, tu problema es el envío del correo. Solventa eso con un correo de prueba y luego le metes todo lo que quieras...

Suponiendo que el correo se llegue a procesar e intentar enviar, podria darse el caso que tengas problemas de SPF/DKIM/DMARC y se quedara en el limbo sin saber donde devolver el mail con el error generado.  Agrega un $mail->Sender = 'correodevuelta@midominio.com'; a las instrucciones de PHPMailer para que te genere el Return-Pathcorrectamente y no se quede en el limbo de tu servidor SMTP sin saber que hacer hasta que al cabo del tiempo se autoelimine por tiempo de expiración durante el envio.

Gracias @masterguru, no sale el correo. No lo envía. No me da ningún error

@OCHOA, a que error te refieres?

@Monica, en la línea mencionada por OCHOA falta la comilla de cierre en la cadena ``contraseña`

@jachguate, en el código está puesta, en el copia pega lo he borrado

@Monica, entonces por favor edita la pregunta y deja el código tal como realmente lo tienes, de otra forma produce confusión en quienes puedan tener la intención de responder y eso reduce tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

@jachguate, disculpa tienes razón. Ya lo he editado

Ese nombre de subdominio que has puesto no tiene ni SPF, ni DMARC y seguramente ni DKIM.  Los mensajes que envies con ese subdominio a cuentas donde eso lo tengan en cuenta seran eliminados o rechazados.  Haz una prueba, y enviatelo a ti mismo, a info@we4you.viessmannes.es.  Para colmo, el SMTP que has puesto no parece existir, es decir, este nombre mail.we4you.viessmannes.es no se resuelve en ninguna IP. No se si son datos de muestra o son reales, pero si son reales peta por todas partes como he explicado.

gracias @masterguru. Son datos de muestra

Revisa este post

Aparte de lo que ya te han comentado los compañeros, veo dos problemas en tu código. 1. Parece un programa inacabado en el sentido de que no aparece claro qué ocurre con el manejo de errores. Por ejemplo, ¿si PHPMailer levanta una Excepción, qué ocurre, te envía un correo avisando de que algo salió mal? ¿muestra algún mensaje al usuario en pantalla? Ese aspecto no se ve claro en el código que nos compartes. 2. No deberías usar ñ ni caracteres especiales en el código (nombres de variable), ni en nombres de tablas, columnas, etc. Y si los usas debes cuidar meticulosamente la codificación ...

... más de uno se ha pasado varias horas, cuando no días y hasta semanas rompiéndose el coco con un código en el que lo que estaba rompiendo todo eran esas ñ y esos acentos en un entorno donde la codificación no se había configurado de forma adecuada (ver por ejemplo esta pregunta). Para evitar eso, es mejor usar siempre una convención de nombre en inglés. Eso tiene además la ventaja de internacionalizar el código y compactarlo, porque los nombres de variable suelen ser más cortos.

ya funciona correctamente. No tenía bien puestos los archivos en form -. Los tenía mal escritos.
